# ios:How to compare 2 NSdates with Different formats?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

i faced a lot of  problem while comparing two NSDate with different format though i am new to this.

-what should be the best  approach to this problem?

1.I tried to convert this two dates in into one format and then go for comparison 
or Should i first Know the format of this two date then go for comparison

Comment: my one date is Like -2012-05-08 12:01:56 +0000                              and another date was in -2011-05-09 10:25:00.627                        I wants to compare dates like this (The upper one is just a example but i need to deal with other format also )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`NSDate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) does not know any thing about it's format. Internally the date is stored without any format or region.

To compare date you can use the [`compare:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method.

```
if([someDate compare:ortherDate] == NSOrderedDescending ){
   // someDate later then otherDate;
}
```

Comment: so you are  basically saying that ,i should compare this 2 dates whit out converting this 2 dates into one format.

Comment: Yes, you should always compare date without converting them. The NSDate object is special designed to make it easier to work with dates, without knowing how the date is going to be represented.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with format? After you initialized the NSDate object, you can directly comapre it to any other object of that type like that: (assuming that `date1` is of type `NSDate`)

```
if ([date1 compare:[NSDate date]] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    ...
}
```

You can see the ref here (look for the `compare` method): https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdate_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: my one date is Like -2012-05-08 12:01:56 +0000                              and another date was in -2011-05-09 10:25:00.627                        i means to say  this kind of format.

Comment: As @rckoenes already answered, the format doesn't matter for comparison as the internal value of the objects is used to do that.